# How can I improve this query to remove "Using Temporary" and "Using Filesort"

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

This query takes quite a long time to run, is there anything I could do to improve upon it?

```
SELECT b.* FROM games_tags bt, games b, tags t 
WHERE bt.tag_id = t.tag_id AND (t.tag_text IN ('flash')) 
  AND b.gameid = bt.game_id AND b.status ='1' 
GROUP BY b.gameid ORDER by rating DESC limit 5952, 16
```

Comment: This isn't a good question; you need to tell us about the tables, how they are designed, what kind of data is in them, and so on. We need more details to help you.

Comment: why you use 'IN' instead of t.tag_text ='flash'

Comment: I'll post more info, and be more clear in just a moment.

Comment: I was editing newlines into the SQL so we could read it without need to scroll horizontally.  Apologies if that messes up your edit.

Comment: I'm using the toxi solution for my current script which can be found http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html

Comment: What this is doing is displaying results in pagination pages from the following tables. games(status), games_tags(game_id,tag_id), and tags(tag_id,tag_text).

Answer (score 0):

Please try using JOIN to join tables correctly in your query